# Compare two arrays and return value if true - wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I m a beginner and try to achieve the following using wordpress:

After a user fill a form , i m storing "location" in array then a wp_table_wordpress

Then i created an other wp_table containing "location" , then I retrieve the content of the wp_table into an array.

So if "location" in the first array match the "location" in the second array
then return true.

But lucky me I m stuck !!

```
                /**
            * User fill form then data are insert into an wp table then an array 

             */
            global $wpdb;

            $name =  $_POST['name'];
            $location = $_POST['location'];
            $service = $_POST['service'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];

            $wpdb->insert('wp_searchform',
                 array(
                      'name'=>$name,
                      'location'=>$location,
                      'service'=>$service,
                      'email'=>$email
                 ),
                 array( 
                      '%s',
                      '%s',
                      '%s',
                      '%s'
                 )
            );

            /**
            * Retrieve data from a wp_table with a mysql join based on location then stored results in an arrays

             */

            $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
                SELECT pro_name
                FROM wp_searchform
                JOIN wp_pro ON wp_searchform.location = wp_pro.location
                LIMIT 0 , 30
               ");

               if ($arraysAreEqual = ($wpdb[0] == $results[0])) 
               {
               echo $results[0]->pro_name;
               }
           else{
               echo "true";
           }
```

Comment: $location isn't an array, so why are you checking $location[0]?

Comment: Well spotted charlotte , i modified the code but it still doesnt work

Comment: `var_dump($results);` do that to get the results of your query. You're not selecting the location in the first place. You only get the field pro_name.

Comment: the var_dump work but I get that output => array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#241 (1) { ["pro_name"]=> string(6) "verity" } } => I'd like to get just the results, not the structure

Comment: Well, you should select the location field in the mysql query too, otherwise you can't compare the locations. var_dump() is only for debugging purpose.

Comment: And now I'm a medium. Great.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP you can run [array intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) on the two arrays and see if the function returns the similarities.

Both arrays will need to have identical structure in order for this to work.

Comment: Please provide more clarification and/or an actual example relevant to WordPress.